# Creating a file using batch does not write %(any text)

Tags: windows, file, batch-file, cmd

I have created a batch file , which is supposed to create an other batch file...
(%passwordw% is set above in my code, but since it is around 300 lines, i didnt bother wasting your time,,,)

```
echo @title .  > "C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Desktop\%passwordw%.bat"
echo @echo off >> "C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Desktop\%passwordw%.bat"
echo set one=%1 >> "C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Desktop\%passwordw%.bat"
echo set filepathname=%~f0 >> "C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Desktop\%passwordw%.bat"
echo set filenameofcaller=%2 >> "C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Desktop\%passwordw%.bat"
echo if %one%== calling goto :callingpassword >> "C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Desktop\%passwordw%.bat"
echo start C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Documents\Notes\Fivos >> "C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Desktop\%passwordw%.bat"
echo @echo off >> "C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Desktop\%passwordw%.bat"
echo exit >> "C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Desktop\%passwordw%.bat"
echo :callingpassword >> "C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Desktop\%passwordw%.bat"
echo call %filenameofcaller% 12 >> "C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Desktop\%passwordw%.bat"
```

but instead of receiving what i "told" batch, i receive this

```
@title .  
@echo off 
set one= 
set filepathname=C:\Users\1\Desktop\Launcher.bat 
set filenameofcaller= 
if == calling goto :callingpassword 
start C:\Users\1\Documents\Notes\Fivos 
@echo off 
exit 
:callingpassword 
call  12
```

I assume that something is wrong with % i have into it, what causes it and how can this be fixed?
I dont know where to start to find where this problem is, since i am pretty new in bash...

Thank you for your time,
Fivos

Answer (score 1):

You should use `%%` instead of `%`.

For example, the third line should look like:

`echo set one=%%1 >> "C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Desktop\%passwordw%.bat"`